# JavaScript: class that returns null

Tags: javascript, class, null, audiocontext

I'm writing a React app in which I use `AudioContext`. Sometimes on certain versions of Safari, calling `new` with `AudioContext` (or `window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;`) returns `null`.

I've written code that guards against this. I was wondering if there is a way to imitate this behaviour? I would like to create a unit test in which I mock `window.AudioContext` to be a class that when called with `new` returns `null`.

How can you achieve something so that:

```js
const context = new FakeAudioContext();
```

sets `context` to `null`?

Comment: This feature is [not fully supported yet on safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_audiocontext_audiocontext)

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you can change the syntax of your call to remove the `new` (or can accept invalid values that aren't `null`)

Comment: @Amy Thanks, I saw that! No it does not. The solutions described there do not work.

Comment: @J.Hesters That's because you can't, and the answers there are the best you can do.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do it like this for the sake of your unit test
`window.AudioContext = null;`

and that way you will simulating the behavior when it's null

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the code calls `new window.AudioContext()` which is different, because it doesn't return `null` but it crashes saying that `null` is not a constructor.